# print QR code with ESC/POS

Tags: java, android, thermal-printer, escpos

I am working with Android printing with thermal printer. Text is printing fine using esc/pos commands.

Instead of working with esc/pos, what is the best higher level library for printing QR codes with thermal printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use ESC/POS for QR-code printing (why?) your only option is to generate the QR-code externally and send the bit image data to the printer.  This is likely more difficult, as you will have to create the bit image in the correct size, and sending bit images to ESC/POS printers is not straight forward either.  Plus it takes more time to transfer the bit image than to let the printer do the work.

Comment: Do you know when did [GS ( k](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=140) start becoming mainstream?

Comment: Actually, no. Sorry.